# How to set Init method for beans automatically created by Component Scanning in spring

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, spring-mvc, postconstruct

In explicity defined beans, it is possible to define the init and destroy methods via annotations, on the Spring configuration class:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan
public class Appconfig {
    @Bean(name="Andre",initMethod="init",destroyMethod="destroy")
    @Scope("singleton")
    public Person person() {
        Person person = new Person(1,"Andre");
        person.setTaxId(5);
        return person; 
    }
```

However, if the bean is created automatically by spring via component scanning, how to do it ?

I have read around that to achieve the same effect with beans created with component scanning, the init method should be annotated with @PostConstruct. However, @PostConstruct is not part of Spring, and when I use this annotation, I have the error

"PostConstruct cannot be resolved to a type".

Somehow, Eclipse seems not to know how to import this annotation automatically. After some more browsing I found out that using

```
import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
```

works, but with an warning saying:

Access restriction: The type 'PostConstruct' is not API (restriction on required library 'C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_45\lib\rt.jar')

So I have 2 questions:

1. Does Spring have a built in mechanism for declaring init and destroy methods on component scanned beans ?
2. Why do I have the error: Access restriction: The type 'PostConstruct' is not API (restriction on required library 'C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_45\lib\rt.jar') when using @PostConstruct ?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: you need to include <context:annotation-config/>   in spring config,  one of the answers makes it clear, how to make annotations available in spring http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5919982/is-there-something-like-predestroy-in-the-spring-as-in-the-castle-windsor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement the `InitializingBean` interface. It declares `afterPropertiesSet` method which should do exactly what you want.

[Spring Javadoc InitializingBean](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/InitializingBean.html)

**J2EE - Spring equivalents**

`@PostConstruct` - `InitializingBean`

`@PreDestroy` - `DisposableBean`

**EDIT:**
Sort of misunderstood the question at first. Creating an interface for `Person` which extends `InitializingBean` or `DisposableBean`, implementing the declared `afterPropertiesSet()`/`destroy()` methods and changing the return type of the `@Bean` annotated method to the interface should do the trick.